# Electrical conductivity of plasmas

Tags: electrical-resistance, plasma-physics

What is the electrical conductivity (or resistance) of plasmas?

I have seen sources mentioning that some plasmas have conductivity in the same order of magnitude as copper or steel and others mentioning that it can be though as infinite, i.e. they are superconductors.

I would like a list/table mentioning the conductivity of different plasmas so to get a clear picture.

Comment: Yes, there are a wide range of conductivities but I fear you are asking for something that may be a bit too broad.  I say this because the range of possible plasma parameters alone can cover more than seven orders of magnitude in temperature and over 20 orders of magnitude in density.  By the way, plasmas can be very conductive but they behave differently than the typical superconductors you may be thinking about (i.e., they do not exclude or "push out" magnetic fields).

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thank you for your input. I had suspected that it would be like that, although I believe that a not exhaustive list can be generated by people working with plasmas.

Comment: Yes, I could create a list but it would take a lot of time since your question is so broad, which is part of my comment.  If you narrow your comment a little, you are likely to get answers.  If you leave it very broad, you are likely to get no responses and the question may even be closed by the moderators.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I understand. I don't want you to spent so much time in it. As I am not very familiar with plasmas I really can't narrow it down. I will just wait in the case someone can provide a general answer. Thank you for your time though. :)

Comment: I would recommend starting with ionospheric studies, as they are routinely estimating the conductivities there (specifically the Pederson and Hall conductivities).  From there you can estimate that the magnetosphere, magnetosheath, and solar wind all have much higher conductivities except in the presence of large amplitude electromagnetic waves (which locally can generate large resistivities).